# How to know if autoscaling has taken place in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-helm

Is there any way to know that the number of pods have scaled up or down as a result of Horizontal Pod Autoscaling apart from kubectl get hpa command?

I want to trigger a particular file on every scale up or scale down of pods

Comment: What does "trigger a file" mean,  do you want to execute some command or apply some k8s config ?

Comment: @murarisumit I basically want to execute a python script immediately on scale out or scale in

Answer (score 1):

You can use status field of HPA to know when was last time HPA was executed.
Details about this can be found with below command:

```
kubectl explain hpa.status
```

from this status , you can use lastScaleTime filed for your problem.

```
lastScaleTime        <string>
 last time the HorizontalPodAutoscaler scaled the number of pods; used by
 the autoscaler to control how often the number of pods is changed.
```